# How to implement a recovery mechanism when a microservice is temporarily unavailable in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices, recovery

I'm learning about microservices communication, and I developed a financial transactions app with these technologies: Spring Boot, Spring MVC, Spring Data JPA and Hibernate Validator.

There are 2 microservices, the first microservice is for validation, it is a REST API with POST methods. And the second microservice is for persistence. And the communication between the 2 microservice is asynchronous and I'm using JMS and ActiveMQ for it.

After that I need to develop a recovery mechanism for the case when one of the microservices is temporarily unavailable. Can someone tell me how can I do this recovery mechanism? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check CircuitBreaker in Spring Boot.

Comment: Checkout this link https://spring.io/guides/gs/circuit-breaker/

Comment: Thank you Sambit and Simon, but is it ok to use a recovery mechanism if the communication between microservices is asynchronous? I want to say that I'm using JMS to send the message from microservice1 to microservice2 and if microservice2 is temporarily unavailable the message is put on the queue and will be send to microservice2 when it will be available, so I think that it isn't necesary a recovery mechanism in this case. Isn't it?

Comment: Why increase the complexity of using both JMS and a queue? Why not use just a message queue, you could use Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hystrix framework for using circuit breaker. Its simply wrapping your class with proxy , if your method considered "not working" based on your configuration its re-direct your call to fallback method.
pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

MainApp

```
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class AppName {}
```

Class that run your business method

```
@Service
public class ClassName {
...
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod="fallbackMethodName")
<method signature> {
  }
…

<method signature> fallbackMethodName(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```